# How to visually re-order elements in a scrolling dropdown input div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to imitate a timepicker with a dropdown like in the Google Calendar. Mine has the following structure:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker-with-dropdown">
<div class="timepicker-select-box">
    <div>00:00</div>
    <div>00:30</div>
    <div>01:00</div>
    ...
    <div>23:30</div>
</div>
```

`.timepicker-select-box` is displayed as a 'dropdown', with the number of displayed rows limited to 7 (like in GC). This can be achieved with CSS:

CSS:

```
.timepicker-select-box {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Everything else works, but the dropdown shows '00:00' on top, whereas it would make more sense to display, say, '12:00' by default (or the value closest to the current selection).

How can I do this?

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/6vdzfua7/) for the current implementation. I am using jQuery (would love to see somebody implementing this on Angular, but maybe that's another question).

Comment: why not using 'select' and 'option'?

Comment: I might just be missing something, but I think your question title doesn't match your question.

Comment: why are you not just using JQuerys Time Picker function

Comment: Also consider placing the value closest to the current selection at the middle, not at the top.

Comment: Could you not use the multiple select component from bootstrap ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls It will be easier to custom to your taste.

Comment: @ReeCube: The idea to use <div> is copied from the Google Calendar. I guess their point is the same as the problem I faced, i.e., with <select> / <option> it is not possible to restrict the number of rows shown in the dropdown (notice the number 7 above).

Comment: @Calvin: please propose a better title, I'll then edit it accordingly.

Comment: @urnotsam: Thanks for your proposal, will be checking it tomorrow...

Comment: @urnotsam: jQuery timepicker is definitely the solution to this particular problem. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll then vote it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @masa i added Jquery time picker as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JQuery Timepicker for this problem. One line of code will fix your problem.  You can download it and read the documentation on it here http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

For example this code will give you your desired output

```
$('#basicExample').timepicker();
```

This open source project as well documented on Github and I suggest you read about it there https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="select-choice-etime">Earliest acceptable time:</label>
<select name="select-choice-etime" id="select-choice-etime">
<option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
<option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
<option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
<option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
<option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
<option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
<option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
<option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
<option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
<option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
<option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
<option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
<option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
<option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
<option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
<option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
<option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
<option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
<option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
<option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
<option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
<option selected="selected" value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
<option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
<option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
<option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
<option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
<option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
<option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
<option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
<option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
<option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

If you convert your timing in AM/PM as shown above you can use the below function.

and function to convert the current time to the nearest half hour in the form used in your options (e.g nearest "10:30 PM" type time) and then a way to use that time to select the proper option.

```
function getNearestHalfHourTimeString() {
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var ampm = "AM";
if (minutes < 15) {
    minutes = "00";
} else if (minutes < 45){
    minutes = "30";
} else {
    minutes = "00";
    ++hour;
}
if (hour > 23) {
    hour = 12;
} else if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
    ampm = "PM";
} else if (hour == 12) {
    ampm = "PM";
} else if (hour == 0) {
    hour = 12;
}

return(hour + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm);
}
```

you can see the desired option with this:

```
$('#select-choice-etime option').removeAttr('selected');

$('#select-choice-etime option[value="' + getNearestHalfHourTimeString() + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zz7pW/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but please see my comment on <select> / <option> above in the original question.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i'll work on it will get back if i get something. Thanks

Comment: The problem has a solution already, see the last comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried do what you ask but i can't move the selected one to top of dropdown

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vdzfua7/3/)

Basically i created a `var` that get  selected `timeArr` index (`line 51, 52`).

Then when fill the dropdown it compare the selected`timeArr` with current `timeArr`  (`line 23`).

If the current `timeArr` is the same of selected `timeArr` it add `id="focus"` to div and then just need to `document.getElementById('focus').scrollIntoView(true)`

Comment: If I had not resorted to jQuery timepicker, I believe I could have resolved my problem with your answer. Thanks!